# Getting Table View Cell text Value in Searchbar Placeholder once a specified cell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

My **ViewController** contains a **Table View**. I am getting data from **JSON** and already able to show this values in my **Table view cell**. There is **Search bar** as well for filtering purpose.

I want to get my **Table View Cell Text** as my **Search bar**
 **placeholder** when that particular cell is clicked.

[image: Showing each cell values]

I want to get **Baramunda** as my **Placeholder text** while that particular cell is clicked.

My code for the same is below.

```
func searchBar(){

    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50));
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
    self.view .addSubview(searchBar)
}
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText == ""
    {
        tableView.alpha = 0.0
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search Location Here"
        parseData()
    }
    else {

        if searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex  == 0 {
            tableView.alpha = 1.0
            areaNameArr = areaNameArr.filter({ (anyobject) -> Bool in
                return (anyobject.lowercased.contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            })

        }
        else {
            print("Do Nothing")
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

{

    return areaNameArr.count

}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" )
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor .black
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor .white
    cell?.textLabel?.text = areaNameArr[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: what you have tried for that? Show some code.

Comment: @srsstyle You want the selected cell's text as search bar's text or search bar's placeholder? I hope you know the difference

Comment: what is the issue ? your question seems trivial.

Comment: @Apogee search bar's placeholder only.

Comment: @Umar I want to get my cell text value in my search bar's placeholder value while licking a particular cell.

Comment: @srsstyle please check the answer I have posted

Comment: @srsstyle check the answer by Apogee, it seems to what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your searchBar variable global to access outside your function searchBar().

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   //here goes your code of viewDidLoad
}
//This is your function for creating search bar ,only first line is changed and rest is same
func searchBar(){
searchBar.frame(forAlignmentRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
self.view .addSubview(searchBar)
}
}
// this delegate method is called when cell is tapped
// remember to connect delegate from storyboard or you can use self.tableView.delegate = self
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //here get the text from tapped cell index
    let tappedCellText = areaNameArr[indexPath.row] as? String
    // here set placeholder
    searchBar.placeholder = tappedCellText
    // when cell is clicked you need to set text of search bar to nil or blank otherwise you would not be able to see placeholder text because some text is already there in search bar
     searchBar.text = ""
    // if you don't cleanup text from search bar you will be required to delete text from search bar manually to see placeholder text
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't help you

Comment: I am getting this error now Invalid redeclaration of 'searchBar()'.  In this line func searchBar(){ .

Comment: Solved @Vikky Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have xcode right now but following should work.

Add following code in your didSelectCell delegate method of your tableView

```
var searchTextField: UITextField? = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
if searchTextField!.responds(to: #selector(getter: UITextField.attributedPlaceholder)) {
    let attributeDict = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    searchTextField!.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: attributeDict)
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide me that method definition (didSelectCell), please.